# Is there any official WCF logo?

Tags: .net, wcf

It would be great to have a logo to put on a brochure for prospective clients. Silverlight has a logo. WPF has a logo : http://windowsclient.net/wpf/ . Where can I find the logo for WCF (windows communication foundation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, their logo is just the .Net one with some text, [the same as on the community site](http://wcf.codeplex.com/):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using [images.google.com](http://www.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&sa=1&q=.net+wcf+logo), [this was the closest](http://www.nikhilk.net/Content/Posts/Images/RIAServicesLogo.png) I could find:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcVR6.png]

Comment: Don't forget `-world -cat -federation -fight -championship -curling -chimpanzee -women` :)